# wordpress theme translation .po/.mo

Tags: wordpress, translation, po

i'm trying to translate custom theme with .po file.
I've found that theme itself prepared for translation (have and example .po and .mo files and calling `load_theme_textdomain(kopa_get_domain(), get_template_directory() . '/languages');` function.

I"ve tried to test it with 404 page with this string:

```
?php _e( "We're sorry, but we can't find the page you were looking for. It's probably some thing we've done wrong but now we know about it we'll try to fix it. In the meantime, try one of these options:", kopa_get_domain() ); ?>
```

I've found it in .po and added a test translation:

```
msgid "We're sorry, but we can't find the page you were looking for. It's probably some thing we've done wrong but now we know about it we'll try to fix it. In the meantime, try one of these options:"
msgstr "sadasf"
```

But nothing changed on the page. What might be the problem in?

Comment: I've tryed `load_textdomain(kopa_get_domain(), get_template_directory().'/languages/en_US.mo')` aswell, nothing changed. function returns "1"